# Python: how to compute the Euclidean distance distribution of a regular network?

Tags: python, networkx, euclidean-distance, loglog

I have an `NxN` regular network, each node of which has an `(X,Y)` set of coordinates. The nodes are separated by the *unit*. The network looks like this:

```
(0,0) (1,0) (2,0)
(0,1) (1,1) (2,1)
(0,2) (1,2) (2,2)
```

I want to be able to compute the *Euclidean distance* from each node to all the others. Example:

```
#Euclidean distances from node (0,0):
0          sqrt(1)     sqrt(4)
sqrt(1)    sqrt(2)     sqrt(5)
sqrt(4)    sqrt(5)     sqrt(8)
```

Then, I want to draw the distance distribution, which tells me with which frequency a given distance has a certain value. I want then to turn the graph into a log-log plot.

This is my attempt:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Creating the regular network    
N=10 #This can vary
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
inds=labels.keys()
vals=labels.values()
inds.sort()
vals.sort()
pos2=dict(zip(vals,inds)) #Dict storing the node coordinates
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos2, with_labels=False, node_size = 15)

#Computing the edge length distribution
def plot_edge_length_distribution(): #Euclidean distances from all nodes
lengths={}
for k, item in pos2:
    for t, elements in pos2:
        if k==t:
            lengths[k]=0
        else:
            lengths[k]=((pos2[t][2]-pos2[k][2])**2)+((pos2[t][1]-pos2[k][1])**2) #The square distance (it's ok to leave it like this)
items=sorted(lengths.items())
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([k for (k,v) in items],[v for (k,v) in items],'ks-')
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")
title_string=('Edge Length Distribution')
subtitle_string=('Lattice Network | '+str(N)+'x'+str(N)+' nodes') 
plt.suptitle(title_string, y=0.99, fontsize=17)
plt.title(subtitle_string, fontsize=9)
plt.xlabel('Log l')
plt.ylabel('Log p(l)')
ax.grid(True,which="both")
plt.show()

plot_edge_length_distribution()
```

**EDIT**

When running, this script throws out the error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, pointing at the line where I wrote `for k, item in pos2:`. **Where is it that I go wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) does this about as efficiently as can be.

Consider the following:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
import numpy as np

coords = [np.array(list(c)) for c in [(0,0),(1,0), (2,0)]]
>>> distance.pdist(coords)
array([ 1.,  2.,  1.])
```

The function returns the upper-right part of the distance matrix - the diagonals are 0, and the lower-left part can be obtained from the transpose.

E.g., the above corresponds to

```
0 1 2
1 0 1
2 1 0
```

with

- the 0 diagonal and everything to its lower-left removed.
- the upper-right "flattened" to [1, 2, 1].

It is not difficult to reconstruct the distances from the flattened result.

Comment: I like this but I guess there's something missing. Say that you have a network of `NxN` nodes: in this case, I'd expect to generate `(N-1)x(N-1)` matrices of the kind you describe. But in your example I fail to see what is the reference node from which the distances `1.`, `2.` etc are computed. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: But a network of *N X N* nodes just means that there are *m = N^2* nodes, no? So the number of distances would be [m choose 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. The total number of distances is m choose 2. This means that we have m choose 2 matrices of distances. But my question is: to what node are the values `1.`, `2.`, etc - that you got from `distance.pdist(coords)` - referring to? Because if the starting node is `(0,0)` I'd expect to have as output `array([0.,1.,2.])`.

Comment: @FC84 See explanation.

Comment: However, why would the distance from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)` be 0, as reported in the reconstructed distance matrix? Isn't it `sqrt(2)`?

Comment: @FC84 But in the example I gave there is no *(1, 1)* element, nor is there a reported 0 (the inferred zeros are on the diagonal, meaning that the distance between any element and itself is 0). I cannot match your last question to my answer.